Error loading LightGBM library in PySpark with Python 3.10.0
Description:
I'm encountering an issue with a LightGBM regressor and classifier when using PySpark in Python 3.10.0.
Environment:
PySpark version: 3.2.1
Python version: 3.10.0
Py4j version: 0.10.9.5
Spark jars packages: com.microsoft.azure:synapseml_2.12:0.11.0
Error Message:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /var/folders/dz/mc23060n2kq52djyhcxl9kmh0000gp/T/mml-natives17452036633252549823/lib_lightgbm.dylib
Steps to Reproduce:

Use LightGBM regressor or classifier with PySpark DataFrame in Python
3.10.0.
Encounter the error mentioned above.

Attempts Made:
I followed the solution provided here and symlinked the installed libomp, but the issue persists.
Detailed Error Stack:
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o5147.fit.
E                   : java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /var/folders/dz/mc23060n2kq52djyhcxl9kmh0000gp/T/mml-natives17452036633252549823/lib_lightgbm.dylib
E                       at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
E                       at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
E                       at java.base/java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
E                       at com.microsoft.azure.synapse.ml.core.env.NativeLoader.loadLibraryByName(NativeLoader.java:66)
E                       at com.microsoft.azure.synapse.ml.lightgbm.LightGBMUtils$.initializeNativeLibrary(LightGBMUtils.scala:33)
E                       at com.microsoft.azure.synapse.ml.lightgbm.LightGBMBase.train(LightGBMBase.scala:37)
E                       at com.microsoft.azure.synapse.ml.lightgbm.LightGBMBase.train$(LightGBMBase.scala:36)
E                       at com.microsoft.azure.synapse.ml.lightgbm.LightGBMRegressor.train(LightGBMRegressor.scala:39)
E                       at com.microsoft.azure.synapse.ml.lightgbm.LightGBMRegressor.train(LightGBMRegressor.scala:39)
E                       at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:151)
E                       at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:115)
E                       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
E                       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
E                       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
E                       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
E                       at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
E                       at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
E                       at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
E                       at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
E                       at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
E                       at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
E                       at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
E                       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Additional Notes:

The issue seems to be related to loading the LightGBM library in Python 3.10.0
I've checked that lib_lightgbm.dylib exists in the specified path.
Any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.


Provide the code you are using.

Are you trying this in synapse?

Yes using synapse ML lightgbm

In synapse spark 3.2 will be retiring soon.

So, i would suggest you to use either spark 3.3 or 3.4.
In any version out of this 2 you will get built in synapseml packages even  LightGBM as shown below.

Here, you can see the synapseml version is 1.0.2 in spark 3.4.
If you wish to configure different version execute below command as mentioned this documentation.
%%configure -f
{
  "name": "synapseml",
  "conf": {
      "spark.jars.packages": "com.microsoft.azure:synapseml_2.12:<version>",
      "spark.jars.repositories": "https://mmlspark.azureedge.net/maven",
      "spark.jars.excludes": "org.scala-lang:scala-reflect,org.apache.spark:spark-tags_2.12,org.scalactic:scalactic_2.12,org.scalatest:scalatest_2.12,com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind",
      "spark.yarn.user.classpath.first": "true",
      "spark.sql.parquet.enableVectorizedReader": "false"
  }
}


@Sumukha G C Check if above provided solution works for you? Let me know if I can be helpful here anyway with further input?
